# "Object of class DateTime could not be converted to string in"

Tags: php

I have two bits of information and would like to save them comma delimited into a file. I would also like to save the timestamp. When I try to do so I get the error "Object of class DateTime could not be converted to string in..."

When I echo the value it comes out fine but when I try to add it to the $data variable the error happens.

Here is my code:

```
<?php


$cont1 = $_POST['cont1'];

$cont2 = $_POST['cont2'];


$timestamp = new DateTime();
$timestamp->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');


$data = "Stuff: $cont1,$cont2,$timestamp";
    $fh = fopen("savestuff.txt", "a");
    fwrite($fh, $data."\r\n");
    fclose($fh);



?>
```

Answer (score 2):

You want something like this

```
$data = "Stuff: $cont1,$cont2," . $timestamp->format('Y-m-d H:i:s') ;
```

The [format](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.format.php) method returns a string, but you are not using its return value. The way you are using it, `timestamp` is still a DateTime object